# <body> has max-width, but background-image is filling entire window

Tags: html, css

I have set my `<body>` to have a max-width and padding left and right. I have then added a repeating background image to the `<body>`. I had hoped the background-image would be constrained by the width (and padding) on the `<body>`. But the background-image is filling the entire width of the screen. Is this to be expected? Do background-images on `<body>` work differently to all other elements?

```css
body {
  max-width: 160rem;
  padding: 0 6.4rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
    background-origin: content-box;
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png");
  background-position: left top;
  }
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to limit the body width, try adding a div element inside the body to act as wrapper of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)